# how to redirect a page for rendering pdf

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am trying to render a report that I have generated and redirected to

I get 404 error but the file exists at the path that i redirected to

the server is GlassFish Server 4.1.1

path: http://asc-pc110:9875/project1/test.pdf

I have successfully rendered a .txt file located at the same location

path: http://asc-pc110:9875/project1/test.pdf

// in file http://asc-pc110:9875/project1/redirection.jsp

`<%

```
response.sendRedirect("test.pdf");
```

%>

`
I expect the rendering of the pdf file either in the browser or in any pdf reader software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to set the content type so that the browser knows it's a pdf file.

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
response.sendRedirect("test.pdf");
```